# element.style and element.classList is undefined

Tags: html

I'm getting errors
`TypeError: todo.style is undefined script.js:75:9`
`TypeError: todo.classList is undefinedscript.js:79:16`
and I'm don't understand where I'm going wrong.

**JS:**

```
const listeOption = document.querySelector('.listes-todo')

listeOption.addEventListener('click', listeToDo);

function listeToDo(e){
const todos = toDoListe.childNodes;

todos.forEach(function(todo){
   switch(e.target.value){
    case "all" : 
    todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;

    case "faire" :
        if(todo.classList.contains('faire')){
            todo.style.display = "flex";
        }else{
            todo.style.display = "none";
        }

   }
   });
} }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="select">
    <select name="todos" class="listes-todo">
        <option value="all">taches</option>
        <option value="faire">terminer</option>
        <option value="taches-termine">taches terminées</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is this variable defined `toDoListe` and is it defined to contain a Collection of Nodes?

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing where `toDoListe` is defined

Comment: that is toDoListe declaration `const toDoListe = document.querySelector('.toDo-liste');`

Comment: Can you share part of your html that has that element with `toDo-liste` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay having looked at your code. This is what you can do.

`toDoListe.children` actually returns a an object on list items using their index as keys. Here's the structure of the sample todos:

```
{
  "0": <li class="faire">First Gather Learning Information</li>,
  "1": <li class="faire">Learn Javascript</li>,
  "2": <li class="faire">Learn CSS</li>,
  "3": <li class>Learn HTML</li>,
  "4": <li class>And Master them well</li>,
  "length": 5,
  "item": function item() { [native code] },
  "namedItem": function namedItem() { [native code] }
}
```

So for example, first item's key is `"0"`... so if you call `toDoListe.children["0"]` returning the first property of that object containing your `todo`'s.

So my proposal is, you want to call your `Object.keys(todos).forEach((key)=>{})` and work with each `todo` by calling `var todo = todos[key]`.

```js
const listeOption = document.querySelector('.listes-todo');
const toDoListe = document.querySelector('.toDo-liste');
listeOption.addEventListener('click', listeToDo);
function listeToDo(e){
  const todos = toDoListe.children;
  
  Object.keys(todos).forEach(function(key){
    var todo = todos[key];

     switch(e.target.value)
     {
        case "all" : 
            todo.style.display = "flex";
          break;

        case "faire" :
          if(todo.classList.contains('faire'))
          {
              todo.style.display = "flex";
          }else{
              todo.style.display = "none";
          }
          break;
     }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" class="toDo-input">
    <button type="submit" class="toDo-botton"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button>
    <div class="select">
        <select name="todos" class="listes-todo">
            <option value="all">taches</option>
            <option value="faire">terminer</option>
            <option value="taches-termine">taches terminées</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<strong>Sample To do List</strong>
<div class="toDo-container">
    <ul class="toDo-liste">
      <li class="faire">First Gather Learning Information</li>
      <li class="faire">Learn Javascript</li>
      <li class="faire">Learn CSS</li>
      <li class="">Learn HTML</li>
      <li class="">And Master them well</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i get this error TypeError: todos.forEach is not a function

Comment: Can you share part of your html that has that element with `toDo-list`e class? then we can help.

Comment: `<form>
    <input type="text" class="toDo-input">
    <button type="submit" class="toDo-botton"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button>

    <div class="select">
        <select name="todos" class="listes-todo">
            <option value="all">taches</option>
            <option value="faire">terminer</option>
            <option value="taches-termine">taches terminées</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="toDo-container">
    <ul class="toDo-liste">
    </ul>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

`toDoListe.childNodes` isn't returning exactly what you are expecting. AS already stated by @Mosia Thabo, you may need to use children or just give each todo element a class e.g `<li class="todo">` that they share and you access them using `var todos document.querySelector('.todo')`.

Otherwise, the above answer is your best solution since `toDoListe.childNodes` returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

todos is an HTML Collection. Use as below

```
todos = toDoListe.children
Array.from(todos).forEach(funtion(todo){})
```

Other ways to iterate it, check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/htmlcollection-for-loop/)